# Connect if there is a running Chrome Driver Instance python

Tags: python-3.x, bots

Objective: First I want to check if any existing instance of chrome driver is running. If not then `get_driver` and `login` will call these two methods. And it's working just fine.
The second step is to call the `checkout_stock` method if the existing instance is running. Since I will never close the driver, there is no need to call the `login` method again.

I am getting the error: `AttributeError: 'CheckOutBot' object has no attribute 'chrome_driver'`

I've never worked with bots so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or doing the right thing. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
import time
import psutil
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
class CheckOutBot:
    def is_chromedriver_running(self):
        for process in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
           if 'chromedriver' in process.info['name']:
              return True
        return False

    def get_driver(self):
        self.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.chrome_options.add_argument("--headless--")
        # self.chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        self.chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options)
        self.chrome_driver.maximize_window()
        self.chrome_driver.get("https://buy.anysite.com/product-page/")
        self.login_url   = "https://buy.anysite.com/login/"
        self.current_url = self.chrome_driver.current_url

    def login(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        email = 'xyz@gmail.com'
        password = '123@xyz'
        time.sleep(2)
        email_input = self.chrome_driver.find_element('id','username')
        email_input.clear()
        email_input.send_keys(email)
        time.sleep(2)
        pass_input = self.chrome_driver.find_element('id', 'password')
        pass_input.clear()
        pass_input.send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.chrome_driver.find_element('id','login-form').submit()

    def checkout_stock(self):
        driver = self.chrome_driver.get("https://buy.anysite.com/product-page/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="html.parser")
        logged_in = soup.find("tr", {"class": "group-header-left"})
        print(logged_in)
        items = soup.find("a", {"class": "text-info"})
        items_processed = []

        for row in items.findAll("middle"):
            row_processed = []
            itemTitle = row.find("tr", {"class": "group-header-left"})
            itemQuantity = row.find("p", {"class": "quantity"})
            status = "Available"

            if itemQuantity and itemQuantity.text == '--':
                status = 'Sold Out'
            
            if itemTitle:
                row_processed.append(itemTitle.text)
                row_processed.append(status)
            
            if row_processed:
                items_processed.append(row_processed)

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(items_processed, columns=["Item Title", "Status"])
        return df
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    checkout_bot = CheckOutBot()
    driver_running = checkout_bot.is_chromedriver_running()
    if driver_running:
        print('running')
        checkout_bot.checkout_stock()
    else:
        print('not running')
        checkout_bot.get_driver()
        checkout_bot.login()
        checkout_bot.checkout_stock()
```